# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<Planner>> above this Planner Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I hope someone can help me out here, I'm stuck on this problem for hours now.

Im trying to build a StreamProivder based on my own model from a Firestore Snapshot. Somehow, every time i declare the type for the StreamProvider `<List<Planner>>`, the `value:`-line gets red underlined.

This is the Stream Provider

```
return StreamProvider<List<Planner>>.value(
  value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).planner,
  child: Scaffold(...
```

This is the Stream in my DataService class:

```
  Stream<List<Planner>> get planner {
    return userCollection.document(uid).collection('Planner').snapshots().map(_plannerFromSnapshot);
  }
```

And here I create my own Data List:

```
  List<Planner> _plannerFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Planner(
        tag: doc.data['Datum'] ?? '',
        tageszeit: doc.data['Tageszeit'] ?? '',
        gericht: doc.data['Gericht'] ?? '',
        plannerID: doc.documentID ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

This is my own Planner model class:

```
class Planner {

  final String tag;
  final String tageszeit;
  final String gericht;
  final String plannerID;

  Planner({this.tageszeit, this.gericht, this.tag, this.plannerID});

}
```

Here is the error hint from AndroidStudio:

> The argument type 'Stream<List> (where Planner is defined in
> ...\lib\models\plannermodel.dart) can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'Stream<List> (where Planner is defined in
> ...\lib\screens\planner.dart).

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message:

> The argument type 'Stream (where Planner is defined in ...\lib\models\plannermodel.dart) can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream (where Planner is defined in ...\lib\screens\planner.dart).

We can see that there are two conflicting definitions of the `Planner` class, one in `models\plannermodel.dart` and one in `screens\planner.dart`.

Thus, we could change the `Planner` class in `screens\planner.dart` to `PlannerScreen` to address this issue.

Comment: Happy to help! Please don't forget to select the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .toList() in the get planner after the .map()